# How to aviod DragControl and OrbitControl working at the same time in Three.js?

Tags: three.js

I have both OrbitControl and DragControl added to my scene, when I try to drag a item with mouse, the rotate event in OrbitControl will also be triggered, is there any way that I can disable rotate event in OribitControl when I drag items ?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/cant-i-use-dragcontrol-and-orbitcontrol-at-the-same-time/4265?u=prisoner849 ?

Comment: @prisoner849 Yes! Thank You man, I know how to do now

Answer (score 2):

One good way to avoid the conflict:

```
dragControl.addEventListener('dragstart',(event)=>{
    orbitControl.enabled = false;
})

dragControl.addEventListener('dragend',(event)=>{
    orbitControl.enabled = true;
})
```